# How do I create a ASP.NET project based on the .NET Core, not on the full Framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I was reading all about .NET Core after hearing about it for months.  I got Visual Studio 2015, so I thought I would try it out.  I go into File - New Project, choose ASP.NET Web Application, and see I can only choose a version of the full .NET Framework (such as 4.6).  **How do I create a ASP.NET project based on the .NET Core, not on the full Framework?**

I thought there would be [some](http://www.bing.com/search?q=create%20%20%22.net%20core%22%20asp.net%20project%20%22visual%20studio%202015%22&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=create%20%22.net%20core%22%20asp.net%20project%20%22visual%20studio%202015%22&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=b8625d064ed74284a2d102d6eccca5af) tutorials [on this](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=create%20%20%22.net%20core%22%20asp.net%20project%20%22visual%20studio%202015%22&oq=create%20%20%22.net%20core%22%20asp.net%20project%20%22visual%20studio%202015%22&gs_l=hp.3...2099.2099.0.2380.2.2.0.0.0.0.358.489.0j1j0j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..2.0.0.0.OFIXnZEFzWA), but I can't find any. All I see is based on the full Framework.

Comment: Just create a project with the default setting and then you'll see in project.json two targets dnx451 (desktop clr) and dnxcore50 (coreclr).

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci can you see/respond to my comments on either answer?  I don't seem to have these options in VS2015.  Is there something separate from the install that needs to be done to get access to the framework and/or the preview templates?

Comment: Try this out https://github.com/aspnet/GetStarted/ is the tutorial for getting things going without Visual Studio. But of course you can still do that if you wish. And good ol' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc

Comment: One other place to look around is https://github.com/aspnet Most of the sample apps are at this location. Enjoy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET 5.0 Core beta5 shipped with VS 2015 RTM. [Beta6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) just shipped and be used to upgrade VS 2015. (Read the Install Instructions!)

When you create a project from one of the ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates (Empty, Web API, or Web Application) it is set up to compile *both* Core and 4.5.1 Framework versions every time you build.

To change this to build *only Core*, do the following:

- Project / Properties / Application: change Platform from .NET
  Framework to .NET Core
- Open project.json and find the "frameworks" section.  Delete
  "dnx451": {}, and save.
- Build

You are now running on the CoreCLR.

Comment: where do you get the preview templates?  They did not come installed with VS2015, at least not on my fresh install.  Framework 5.0 is not available on the dropdown list of frameworks, and not listed on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx?source=VS2013

Comment: When you install VS2015 if you select the Web / ASP.NET components you get the ASP.NET 5 templates that Van mentions. So, if you have *any* ASP.NET stuff in there, you have ASP.NET 5 as well.

Comment: In Project / Properties / Application: My Platform says "N/A" when I chose a ASP.NET 4.6 project template. I had to choose ASP.NET 5 Preview templates.  I presume the 4.6 will go away or otherwise be obvious once ASP.NET 5 is done.

Comment: In the RTM version when using an ASP.NET 5 Preview Template, I do not see .NET Core as a platform option.  Is it because I got this error http://i.imgur.com/Rs6fM45.png ?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski that looks like it might be a bug. Can you log an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues with a link to the screenshots and any other relevant info?

Comment: And regarding whether the ASP.NET 4.x template will disappear when ASP.NET 5 is released, that is unlikely. Because there are such significant differences between those two versions of ASP.NET, it is most likely that the two will be offered side-by-side for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Yep, now I understand this all better; ASP.NET 5 is now renamed to ASP.NET Core, and still isn't out.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the .net core and nightly builds at:

https://github.com/dotnet/core

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

Thanks for the comments and whatnot guys... Can't delete my answer since it's accepted, so here's some screenshots showing how to get to the new template.  Note that the new framework version is not listed where you (at least I) would expect.  You can choose the asp.net 5 tempate after you actually choose to create a web application in one of the (non 5.0) framework templates.

[image: VS version]

[image: No Preview templates]

[image: Not on framework list]

[image: I stand corrected :P]

Comment: That explains a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kritner this answer is incorrect. Please see Van's answer.

Comment: @Eilon I commented on the answer (how did the two of you manage to answer and comment within 2 minutes of another? :O)  I don't have the options called out in the answer from Van, are you sure it was shipped with VS2015 or is it installed separately?

Comment: @Kritner I work with Van and he emailed me. It ships in VS2015 RTM (and its various previews when they shipped).

Comment: @Kritner select the ASP.NET project template and you'll see options there for ASP.NET 4.6 and for ASP.NET 5 preview.

Comment: ah, well that was not expected.

Comment: I tried to follow the screenshots, and I go into my project properties.  I got an error as follows: http://i.imgur.com/Rs6fM45.png, then I look in Application > Solution DNX SDK version: 1.0.0-beta5 with Platform .NET Framework.  Am I correct in thinking that .NET Core should be a platform option as well?