# How to convert .net 4.6 project to 5.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687788/how-do-i-create-a-asp-net-project-based-on-the-net-core-not-on-the-full-framew), I now know how to create a *new* project using the 5.0 framework (and have successfully done so), however is there an upgrade path to converting a 4.6 project (or earlier) to a 5.0?

I know there are a lot of changes in between the two frameworks, so maybe it has not yet been documented/developed - but I am not sure (and was unable to find the info), so figured I'd ask.

When going into project properties I am presented with:

Project Properties

[image: Project Properties]

Right click menu on project

[image: Right click menu on project]

Which are the two areas I would expect such a conversion be possible.  Am I looking in the wrong place, or does the upgrade not yet exist (or even will it?)

Comment: Have you checked that the 5.0 framework is correctly installed, that is, can you create a (new) working 5.0 project ?

Comment: @cosmo0 I am able to create a .net core project using the preview templates when creating a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need to create an ASP.NET 5 project and then copy-paste useful code around.

The designs (MVC, Web API and SignalR) are different, so you could not easily migrate yet. Compared to those changes, the .NET Framework vs. .NET Core/DNX changes are subtle.

References

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the links that helps.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 5 doesn't exist yet. It is .NET 4.6 which was just released. The latest version of ASP.NET is version 5.0, which uses up to .NET 4.6. .NET Core 5 is a totally different thing, and there aren't predefined migration paths to it.

You can't just convert a regular ASP.NET 4 project to a ASP.NET 5 project since the introduction of the entirely new Core framework. You have to do it by hand yourself.

Comment: The .NET Framework to .NET Core migration can be easier here, as ASP.NET 5 will support both. However, ASP.NET 5 is a different monster from ASP.NET 4.*, and that's the tough migration for web sites/apps at this stage.

Comment: Ah, migration path - that was the term I was trying to recall when writing the question.